# Flutter Firebase Password less Authentication auth.isSignInWithEmailLink(link) returns false

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to build an app with Flutter and Firebase password-less authentication. I'm able to receive  the email from Firebase but when I like on the link

> auth.isSignInWithEmailLink(link) says false.

My pubspec.yaml firebase dependencies

```
firebase_core: ^1.0.3
firebase_auth: ^1.0.2
firebase_dynamic_links: ^2.0.2
```

Here is the full Login code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_dynamic_links/firebase_dynamic_links.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static String tag = "login page";
  @override
  LoginPageState createState() => new LoginPageState();
}

class LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  String _email;

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.initDynamicLinks();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  void initDynamicLinks() async {
    FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink(
        onSuccess: (PendingDynamicLinkData dynamicLink) async {
      final Uri deepLink = dynamicLink?.link;

      if (deepLink != null) {
        print('DeepLink: ' + deepLink.path);

        await _signInWithEmailAndLink(deepLink.toString());
      }
    }, onError: (OnLinkErrorException e) async {
      print('onLinkError');
      print(e.message);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final snackBarEmailSent = SnackBar(content: Text('Email Sent!'));
    final snackBarEmailNotSent = SnackBar(
      content: Text('Email Not Sent. Error.'),
    );

    final email = TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      autofocus: false,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) return "Email cannot be empty";
        return null;
      },
      onSaved: (value) => _email = value,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Email',
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.mail),
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)),
      ),
    );

    final loginButton = Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
      child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text("Send Verification Email"),
          onPressed: (() async => await validateAndSave()
              ? ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBarEmailSent)
              : ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                  .showSnackBar(snackBarEmailNotSent))),
    );

    final loginForm = Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24, right: 24),
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(height: 50),
          email,
          SizedBox(height: 40),
          loginButton
        ],
      ),
    );
    return Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Center(child: loginForm));
  }

  Future<bool> validateAndSave() async {
    final FormState form = _formKey.currentState;
    if (form.validate()) {
      form.save();
      bool sent = await _sendSignInWithEmailLink();
      return sent;
    }
    return false;
  }

  Future<bool> _sendSignInWithEmailLink() async {
    final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    try {
      auth.sendSignInLinkToEmail(
          email: _email,
          actionCodeSettings: ActionCodeSettings(
              url: 'https://<MyApp>.page.link/<key>',
              handleCodeInApp: true,
              androidInstallApp: true,
              androidMinimumVersion: "12"));
    } catch (e) {
      _showDialog(e.toString());
      return false;
    }
    print(_email + "<< sent");
    return true;
  }

  Future<void> _signInWithEmailAndLink(link) async {
    final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    // final PendingDynamicLinkData data =
    //     await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
    // final Uri deepLink = data?.link;
    print('Link: ' + link);
    bool validLink = auth.isSignInWithEmailLink(link);
    print('Is Valid Link: ' + validLink.toString());
    if (validLink) {
      try {
        print('email:' + _email);
        print('link:' + link);
        await auth.signInWithEmailLink(email: _email, emailLink: link);
      } catch (e) {
        print('Error' + e);
        _showDialog(e.toString());
      }
    }
  }

  void _showDialog(String error) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: new Text("Error"),
          content: new Text("Please Try Again.Error code: " + error),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new TextButton(
              child: new Text("Close"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Let me know what I'm missing here.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try the plugin [app_links](https://pub.dev/packages/app_links) along with firebase_dynamic_links.

Sample Code

```
Future<bool> retrieveDynamicLinkAndSignIn() async {
        try {
          await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
          final _appLinks = AppLinks(
            onAppLink: (Uri uri, String url) {
              appLogs('onAppLink[$url][$uri]');
            },
          );
          final deepLink = await _appLinks.getInitialAppLink();
          appLogs('appLinks.uri[$deepLink]');
          if (deepLink != null) {
            bool validLink =
            _firebaseAuth.isSignInWithEmailLink(deepLink.toString());
            if (validLink) {
              String email = SPService.instance.getString('email') ?? '';
              appLogs('retrieveDynamicLinkAndSignIn[$email]');
              if (email.isEmpty) {
                return false;
              }
              SPService.instance.setString('email', '');
    
              final firebase_auth.UserCredential userCredential =
              await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailLink(
                email: email,
                emailLink: deepLink.toString(),
              );
              if (userCredential.user != null) {
                await _setUserFromFirebaseUser();
                logLogin(SignUp.email, true);
                return true;
              } else {
                logLogin(SignUp.email, false);
                AppToast.info(strings.noCredentialsWereFound);
              }
            } else {
              appLogs('Link is not valid');
              AppToast.info(strings.noCredentialsWereFound);
            }
          } else {
            appLogs('retrieveDynamicLinkAndSignIn.deepLink[$deepLink]');
          }
        } catch (e, s) {
          AppToast.error(null, e, s);
        }
        return false;
      }
```